# Left join with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, left-join, inner-join, rails-activerecord

I have these models :

Sections have multiple Questions

Questions have one Answer

One Answer belongs to one User and one Question

So I would like request for a specified user, all Sections with linked Questions et linked Answer EVEN if there is no Answer

```
Section.joins(questions: :answer).where(answers: { user_id: USER_ID })
```

Will return only Section that have a question with answer.

```
Section.joins(questions: :answer).where(answers: { user_id: USER_ID })
```

This doesn't work :

```
Section.joins(:questions).includes(questions: :answer).where(answers: { user_id: USER_ID })
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to write the left join yourself.

```
Section.joins("left join questions on questions.section_id = sections.id")
  .joins("left join answers on answers.question_id = questions.id")
```

Comment: Its not working for me. Returns only that records that have a questions.